# How to access the same IP using different network interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, ip

I have three wlan interfaces attached in my RaspberryPi:

- `wlan0`
- `wlan1`
- `wlan2`

Each of them is connected to the **different SSID**:

- `gopro-0`
- `gopro-1`
- `gopro-2`

GoPro cameras are set as a WiFi router, have **always the same IP address**: `10.5.5.9`.

With this configuration if I call:

```
curl http://10.5.5.9
```

then first `wlan0` interface will be used (simplified assumption). If I'd like to call the camera `gopro-2`, I hve to invoke:

```
curl http://10.5.5.9 --interface wlan2
```

It works. However there is a problem that not all commands allows me to specify the interface (i.e. `ffmpeg` - or I don't know about it).

Is it possible to somehow trick Linux and *delegate* some IP address to be forwarded to `10.5.5.9` on specific interface?

For example:

```
10.5.4.100 -> 10.5.5.9 @ wlan0
10.5.4.101 -> 10.5.5.9 @ wlan1
10.5.4.102 -> 10.5.5.9 @ wlan2
```

I would appreciate any solution or even other approach that will let me call the same IP on different interface using regular HTTP GET/POST methods.